# Can I use software to measure the frequency (in Hertz) that information is being sent?

Tags: c++, ethernet, bandwidth, data-transfer, memory-bandwidth

I have two computers which send and receive data from each other via reflective memory.

Using time stamps I have been able to determine the time to transfer a 32 bit int (in this case 0.2313ms). I need to know the how much bandwidth is being used in hertz (Hz) to make sure I meet the project requirements. Is there a software based way (preferably C++) to determine this? From what I can tell I can't simply convert between bps and hertz.

Comment: Have you read this - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56265/difference-between-hz-and-bps ?

Comment: What transport are you using?  Ethernet?

Comment: Yes, we are using ethernet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That's not a C++ problem, though : you simply have not nearly enough information to even *guess* at the bandwidth. You have one latency measure, but no encoding knowledge, no signal-to-noise ratios, no sustained throughput measures, ...